# Проверка нажатия кнопки submit

Tags: веб-программирование, файлы, php, отправка, сервер

Есть пример из книги (также есть подобный вопрос возник после просмотра видеурока) по отправки файлов с компьютера пользователя на сервер:

1) Форма для отправки файла:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Administration — upload new files</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Upload new news files</h1>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method=post>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000">
Upload this file: <input name="userfile" type="file">
<input type="submit" value="Send File">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

2) PHP-код, обрабатывающий отправку файла на сервер:

```
<head>
<title>Uploading...</title>
</head>
<body>
<hl>Uploading</h1>
<?
if ($_FILES['userfile']=="none")
{
    echo "Problem: no file uploaded";
    exit;
}
if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']==0)
{
    echo "Problem: uploaded file is zero length";
    exit;
}
if ($_FILES['userfile']['type'] != "text/plain")
{
    echo "Problem: file is not plain text" ;
    exit;
}
if (!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['name']))
{
    echo "Problem: possible file upload attack";
    exit;
}
$upfile = "/home/book/uploads/".$userfile_name ;
if (!copy($_FILES['userfile']['name'], $upfile))
{
echo "Problem: Could not move file into directory";
exit ;
}
echo "File uploaded successfully<br><br>" ;
$fp = fopen ($upfile, "r") ;
$contents = fread ($fp, filesize ($upfile) ) ;
fclose ($fp) ;
$contents = strip_tags ($contents) ;
$fp = fopen ($upfile, "w") ;
fwrite($fp, $contents) ;
fclose ($fp) ;
echo "Preview of uploaded file contents : <br><br>" ;
echo $contents;
echo "<br><br>" ;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

У меня возникли следующие вопросы:

1) **Почему в html-коде у кнопки типа `submit` не задано свойство `name`, например, `name="send"` и впоследствии обработка свойств посылаемого файла в php-коде не происходит внутри следующего условия:**

```
if (isset($_POST['send'])
{
    if ($_FILES['userfile']=="none")
    {
        echo "Problem: no file uploaded";
        exit;
    }
    if ($_FILES['userfile']['size']==0)
    {
        echo "Problem: uploaded file is zero length";
        exit;
    }
        ....
}
```

(в видеуроке также не используется условия нажатия на кнопу типа `submit` и используется условие `if ($_FILES)`)

2) **Прочитав http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-uploaded-file.php , правильно ли я понял, что функция `is_uploaded_file` проверяет был ли выбран файл с компьютера для отправки на сервер?**

**Обновление**

@eicto На данный момент `upload2.php` имеет вид:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Uploading...</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <hl>Uploading</h1>
<?php
if (!isset($_FILES["userfile"])) die ("Problem: no file uploaded");
$tmp_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];

if (!is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)) die ("Problem: possible file upload attack"); //на самом деле можно посмотреть код ошибки 
//if ($_FILES["userfile"]["size"]) die ("Problem: uploaded file is zero length");
//if ($_FILES['userfile']['type']!="text/plain") die ("Problem: file is not plain text");
if (file_exits("Z:/home/book/uploads/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'])) die ("File already exits"); // тут надо как-то обрабатывать эту ситуацию

$contents=strip_tags(file_get_contents());

echo $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']."<br>";
echo $_FILES['userfile']['name']."<br>";

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"Z:/home/book/uploads/".$_FILES['userfile']['name']) || die ("Problem: Could not move file into directory");

echo "File uploaded successfully<br><br>" ;
echo "Preview of uploaded file contents : <br><br>" ;
echo $contents;
echo "<br><br>" ;
?>
</body></html>
```

и на выбор существующего файла для отправки на сервер выдает:

Uploading Problem: possible file upload attack

Answer (score 1):

по первому пункту не хочется отвечать, т.к. там и код страшный и всё остальное...

по второму: 
Нет т.к. функция

> Возвращает TRUE, если файл filename был загружен при помощи HTTP POST. Это полезно для удостоверения того, что злонамеренный пользователь не пытается обмануть скрипт так, чтобы он работал с файлами, с которыми работать не должен - к примеру, /etc/passwd.

т.е. функция проверяет, действительно ли файл в аргументе был загружен на сервер.

ваш код можно переписать вот так:

```
<html>
 <head>
   <title>Uploading...</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Uploading</h1>
<?php
if (!isset($_FILES["userfile"])) die ("Problem: no file uploaded");
$tmp_name = $_FILES["userfile"]["tmp_name"];

if (!is_uploaded_file($tmp_name)) die ("Problem: possible file upload attack"); //на самом деле можно посмотреть код ошибки 
if ($_FILES["userfile"]["size"]) die ("Problem: uploaded file is zero length");
if ($_FILES['userfile']['type']!="text/plain") die ("Problem: file is not plain text");
if (file_exists("/home/book/uploads/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'])) die ("File already exist"); // тут надо как-то обрабатывать эту ситуацию

$contents=strip_tags(file_get_contents());

move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"/home/book/uploads/".$_FILES['userfile']['name']) || die ("Problem: Could not move file into directory");

echo "File uploaded successfully<br /><br />" ;
echo "Preview of uploaded file contents : <br /><br />" ;
echo $contents;
echo "<br /><br />" ;
?>
</body></html>
```

Обратите внимание на порядок проверок. В вашем примере все было перепутано.

*вы всё делаете неправильно - выкиньте вы эту книжку и не смотрите видеоуроков, лучше попробуйте написать свою программу*

Comment: @eicto все-таки что насчет первого вопроса: вы тоже не использовали в php коде проверку 

    if (isset($_POST['nameinputsubmit']
      {
      }
Почему?

Comment: а зачем если я могу проверить наличие `$_FILES['userfile']` ? к тому же у submit не задано имя...

Comment: кстати, закрывайте теги input вот так:

     <input name="userfile" type="file" />

и не используйте `<?` т.к. сейчас по умолчанию short_open_tags=Off. пишите `<?php`

Comment: @eicto ваш код выдает

    Problem: Could not move file into directory.
С закомментированной строкой

    if (file_exits("/home/book/uploads/".$_FILES['userfile']['name'])) die "File already exits"; // тут надо как-то обрабатывать эту ситуацию
т. к. при ее незакомментированности выдавало

    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING in Z:\home\z.ru\www\upload2.php on line 14
Также функция file_get_contents требует параметра. Какой использовать?

Comment: я там скобки пропустил. исправил 20 минут назад. 

---

у вас директория /home/book/uploads/ существует ? доступна пользователю вебсервера на запись ?

Comment: @eicto я попробовал вывести временный путь на сервере и путь к файлу:

    echo $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']."<br>";
    echo $_FILES['userfile']['name']."<br>";
и вывелось несмотря на то, что было добавлено 2 оператора одна строка и как я понял из комментирования этих операторов срабатывает лишь 2-й оператор, т.е. видимо временный путь на сервере не установлен. Причем это в моем php-файле такое поведение, а в вашем если эти строки поместить перед строкой

    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,"/home/book/uploads/".$_FILES['userfile']['name']) ...
не выводит ни один из путей.