# Равносильность функции move_uploaded_file и функций is_uploaded_file, copy

Tags: веб-программирование, php, загрузка, сервер, функции

В связи с вопросом на [Проверка нажатия кнопки submit](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/244770/php-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8-submit) я прочитал следующие страницы на http://php.net/manual/ru/function.copy.php , http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php , http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-uploaded-file.php . Правильно ли я понял из содержания этих страниц, что функция `move_uploaded_file` и функции `is_uploaded_file` вместе с `copy` равносильны?

Comment: Нет, это разные функции. Читайте внимательнее.

Answer (score 2):

Проясню ситуацию.

Немного, как говорится лирики

В PHP есть некий режим, который ограничивает работу с файловой системой за пределами сайта.
Т.е например сайт расположен по пути:
`/web/my_super_site/public_html`
и действуют ограничения на `/web/my_super_site/` (работать с файловой системой выше папки `/web/my_super_site` не разрешается)

А файлы как правило аплоадятся в `/tmp/` т.е доступ туда нам может быть запрешен.

Теперь по сути вопроса:

`is_uploaded_file` можно сравнить с `file_exists`, но первая функция, грубо говоря, игнорирует запрет на работу с файловой системой.

`move_uploaded_file` сравнимо с `rename`, но так же как и в первом случае, первая функция , грубо говоря, игнорирует запрет на работу с файловой системой.